# Is it possible to test height and width of controls on a page

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, qunit

When using multiple browsers some controls appear out of the range of a page and some seems scattered using different browsers. Is there any way to write unit tests for all these layouts. I am exploring jquery testing with qunit, js-test-driver. But i don't know how to do this.

Comment: I have not tried just looking how can we do this. Tried doing simple tests with qunit but need that involves layout testing

Answer (score 0):

Write unit tests (using QUnit for example) like this:

```
var range = 10;

function rangeCheck(number1, number2) {
    return (number1 >= number2 - range) && (number1 <= number2 + range);
};

test("#main size", function() {
    var $main = $('#main');
    ok(rangeCheck($main.width(), 500), "Width ok.");
    ok(rangeCheck($main.height(), 500), "Height ok.");
});
```

Of course it's only example, you can improve this, but with small amount of code it could improve workflow.